# ParseFacebookUtilsV4 symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Tags: objective-c, facebook, parse-platform

Upgraded ParseFacebookUtils to ParseFacebookUtilsV4 and receiving this error.  I'm using version 1.8.5 of ParseFacebookUtilsV4 and 1.8.5 of Parse.  I used cocoapods to install.  Many answers on SO say to include the Facebook SDK, but I can't do that because then I get symbol duplications because of the FBSDKCoreKit library which is a dependency of ParseFacebookUtilsV4.

Please help, I've been struggling with this for hours.  Is there any workaround that anyone has found.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should check your CocoaPods projects. In Build Settings of each project, check the Architectures and it should look something like this:

**Architectures: $(ARCHS_STANDARD)

Valid Architectures: armv7 armv7s arm64**

Also try this:

**Build For Active Architectures to YES**